# JavaScript - static variables?

Tags: javascript

I have an input type="text", its default value is "Mike". When the user clicks on it, the value is supposed to be set to '' (empty), and when it goes out of focus, its supposed to go back to "Mike" (unless the user changed the value to another name). What I've done is:

```
<input type="text" id="TxtFname" style="width:50%" runat="server"
    onfocus="firstText = this.text;if(this.value!=''){this.value='';}"
    onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value=firstText;}" />
```

and in the top of the page, in the head content place holder:

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="jv">
    var firstText;
</script>
```

for some reason it keeps "forgetting" whats firstText's value is, so it sets the textbox value to "undefined". 
Is there a way to create a static variable, so firstText's value doesn't reset every time?

Comment: You really should be using the `placeholder` attribute for such things…

Answer (score 2):

You should be setting `firstText` to the input's `value` attribute.

```
firstText = this.value;
```

Otherwise, `this.text` is not a defined property on the input element so its value gets defaulted to `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought text and value were the same thing. this solved my problem.